# Pass value from Textview in dialog to Asynctask

Tags: android, dialog, android-asynctask, parameter-passing

i am having a problem passing values from a textview in a dialog to asynctask to add to database, here is the code:

```
public void addfooddialog(View v){
     final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
     dialog.setContentView(R.layout.addfooddialog);
     dialog.setTitle("Insert food");
     dialog.setCancelable(false);
     dialog.show();
     Button b = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.addfood);
     b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
             public void onClick(View v) {
              new add().execute();
               }
         });
    }
```

and here is the class extending AsyncTask

```
   class add extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    Dialog d= new Dialog(context);
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
       super.onPreExecute();
       d.setContentView(R.layout.addfooddialog);
       Log.i("","ata3 men hon");

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        TextView title= (TextView)d.findViewById(R.id.plattername);
        TextView description= (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.description);
        TextView price= (TextView)d. findViewById(R.id.price);
            String foodname = title.getText().toString();
            String fooddescription = description.getText().toString();
                    String foodprice = price.getText().toString();
```

---

```
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("title", foodname));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", fooddescription));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", foodprice));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_add,
                "POST", params);
        final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created product
                Log.i("sucees","---------------------------------");

                // closing this screen
                finish();
            } else {
                // failed to create product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

}
   }
```

Now i know that the dialog is being recreated and this is why the values return to null, but how to i pass the values directly to the asynctask class?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please format your code properly and remove unrelated lines like the Logging and so on. Its really hard to find out whats going on here with all that uneccesary code wrapped around.

Comment: okay edited...i am adding food title, description and price, in the dialog i fill the textfields and click on the button , onclick it should pass the values to the asynctask so that it posts them in the database...

Comment: can you please edit it properly and please refactor code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create global variable that take the value from `EditText` and using the variable in `AsyncTask` class

Comment: yea i just tried it a just a couple of minutes ago and it worked. thank you anw :)

Comment: also you can use sharedpreferences to save critical data and save it with you all activity cycle  , 

could you mark answer as accepted to help others